# Blender modeling materials in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: materials, unreal-engine

I'm new to Blender and also Unreal. In Unreal material object is a place for material elements. In 3DS Max you can create Submaterial for it but I don't know how to do it in Blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it's a bit hard to tell, but are you talking about placing Materials in Material Slots? If so, you can do it through the Material Properties Tab:

[image: MaterialSlots]

Comment: Thats what i want. thank you.